# Changing the title of a UIButton attributedStrings enumerateSubstrings strings ranges

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring, swift4

There are a few variations of this question on SO - but none seem to have an up to date answer for Swift 4... I want to set the title of a UIButton with an attributed string that has part of the string in bold and part not. I am trying this code based on the new range in Swift 4.
But the code doesn't seem to affect the substring. Has anyone got this working?`

```
     let text = NSLocalizedString("     BOLD TEXT not \r\n  bold text", comment: "")
     let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

     text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, options: .byWords) {
         (substring, substringRange, _, _) in
         if substring == "BOLD TEXT" {
             attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30),
                                           range: NSRange(substringRange, in: text))
        }
}
      cell.multiFunctionButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)`
```

As @larme says below BOLD Text is two words.

So I ended up using this:

```
let str = NSString(string: text)
let theRange = str.range(of: "BOLD TEXT")
let attribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20),
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
attributedString.addAttributes(attribute, range: theRange)
```

Comment: Print `substring` in the closure, you'll see why it may not work. You are enumerating words, but "BOLD TEXT", that's TWO words, so `substring` may never equal to "BOLD TEXT". Well, I used "may", because you are using localizedString, and we don't know what's the value behind it.

Comment: What exact result you expect - share here a snapshot (image) to get better help

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to your snippet:

```
        (substring, substringRange, _, _) in
        print(substring)
        if substring == "BOLD TEXT" {
```

You will see in console that `if` clause is never executed, because your substrings are never matched against "BOLD TEXT":

`Optional("BOLD")
Optional("TEXT")
Optional("not")
Optional("bold")
Optional("text")`

to get a range of "BOLD TEXT" use `let subtringRange = str.range(of: "BOLD TEXT")`

So the proper solution to prepare attributed string for the button is:

```
let text = NSLocalizedString("     BOLD TEXT not \r\n  bold text", comment: "")
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

guard let substringRange = text.range(of: "BOLD TEXT") else {          
    return
}
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30),
                                          range: NSRange(substringRange, in: text))
```